# How can I make a downloader from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a Web Server that has some files I want to sell, and I want some way to download them to the client. I made my own HTTP server, so that's not a problem, and I can program HTML and CSS, and a tiny bit of JavaScript. I've seen tutorials on making a download link with HTML 5, but I can't use that, because I need to charge a bill. I want to do this with JavaScript, so I seem to have two options:

a) Input credit card info to my Server, and have it return the file bytes. The problem with this is, I know I can use Sockets in JavaScript, but how do I download it to my client? Or

b) Have a normal link, but have JavaScript write the credit card info in an HTTP Header for my HTTP Server to deal with.

Either way, I want the money transactions to happen on my Server-side. I'll use the Java Billing API for the transactions, and my Server is coded in Java.

Any help is much appreciated!

-Alden

Comment: Send the payment data in an Ajax request (over SSL, that's sensitive data) and have the request handler return the binary data you want the user to download. You can then use the File API to turn this data into a download.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about encryption! That would've been bad! But how can I encrypt the data in JavaScript, then decrypt it in Java? Also, what's the File API? That sounds helpful!

Comment: I'll give you some general advice: a) Don't bother coding things that already exist and are robust, free and safe (i.e., HTTP servers: try Apache, nginx, take your pick). b) If you hadn't thought about encryption, you really need to stop, take a breath and take your time to learn the basics before you get in **serious** trouble. c) Try googling things before you ask them. [Here's the first result](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) you get when searching "File API".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually easier then you might think

```
    <input type=button id="Buy" onclick="location.href='file location here'" value="Name of file/BUY">
```

You will of course need javascript or some php of you gonna sell a product and require them to purchase it before they can download it but for downloads thats all you need

Comment: Can I force the HTTP Request to be sent through JavaScript? Then I could set an HTTP header with the encrypted credit info?

Comment: Never mind I figured out the JavaScript. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your welcome if you ever need any more help feel free to send the question to stackoverflow and then share it with me